# Why is NavigationService null in Page constructor?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `NavigationWindow` that hosts pages. When navigating to a Page, in its constructor, calling `NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this)` yields null, but in the Page_Loaded event it returns the desired object.

The thing is, regardless which page is loaded, the `NavigationService` object is the same. I checked this using `GetHashCode()`.

So if it really is the same object every time, why does it have to be null in the `Page` constructor? And why do I have to pass a `DependencyObject`, when it returns the same object anyway?

Is there anything that prevents me from assigning the NavigationService object to a static variable and reuse it?

Comment: Hi, isn't it this property that you need? [`Page.NavigationService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.navigationservice(v=vs.110).aspx)... [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.getnavigationservice(v=vs.110).aspx) they mention this: "The NavigationService that processed the navigation to a Page can be accessed from the Page itself by getting the value of its Page.NavigationService property."

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi yes, you are right, this is exactly the property I need. Unfortunately, it is null in the constructor. afaik the first time it is not null is in the Page_Loaded event